# Pegar posição prefab e comparar com outras prefab dentro de um grid? Unity 3D

Tags: c#, android, unity3d, jogos

estou desenvolvendo um jogo estilo tetris, porem voltado para quimica. Ao invés de sumir uma linha completa e pontuar, o usuário precisa formar uma molécula. Pra isso, cada elemento (H e C) sao um prefab diferente. Com isso eu preciso identificar se o elemento C tem 4 H ao seu redor, para formar uma molécula e assim pontuar e sumir somente esses blocos. Dai minha duvida.. como faço pra pegar a posição que o C vai se encaixar no grid e comparar se próximo dele tem mais 4H? eu fiz isso, mas não funfou. Pode me ajudar?

```
public void Verifica(){


  while(gameStarted){

  for (int y = 0; y < gridHeight; ++y) {
   for (int x = 0; x < gridWidth; ++x) {
     if (Grid [x, y] == (GameObject)Instantiate(Resources.Load("Prefab/C"))) {
     Debug.Log ("Hello");//teste
      if(Grid[x+1,y] == (GameObject)Instantiate(Resources.Load("Prefab/H"))){
      cont++;
     }
      else if(Grid[x-1,y] == (GameObject)Instantiate(Resources.Load("Prefab/H"))){
      cont++;
     }
      else if(Grid[x,y+1] == (GameObject)Instantiate(Resources.Load("Prefab/H"))){
      cont++;
     }
      else if(Grid[x,y-1] == (GameObject)Instantiate(Resources.Load("Prefab/H"))){
      cont++;
     }
    }

    }Debug.Log ("Hello"+ cont); //teste
  }
 }
 }
```

Se cont++ == 4 fechou os elementos e pontuara.
se nao ele continuara fazendo a verificação com os restantes dos blocos..

OBS: os meus blocos sao formados apenas pelas prefabs C e H. que cairão de modo aleatório

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sua comparação está instanciando uma nova entidade de em base de um prefab, a comparação **NUNCA** vai ser true, e provavelmente seu `cont` sempre será zero.

Para realizar esse tipo de comparação recomendo usar tags, defina um valor na prefab para os objetos de C e outra tag para os objetos de H. Com isso, a princípio se a `Grid` for de `GameObject`s é só fazer `Grid[x,y].tag == "tag"`.

Toda sua lógica pra construção do jogo fica igual, só muda o que mencionei que na hora de verificar ao invés de criar uma nova instância, verificar pela tag.

As tags são definidas neste ponto da tela:

[image: Edição de tags]

Você pode usar o Add Tag pra ter outras opções que facilitem identificar melhor os teus objetos. Faça essa alteração no Prefab, porque aí todas as novas instâncias dentro do jogo vão refletir essa mudança da Tag.

Comment: DH. obgado pela resposta. Eu entendi o que falou, mas como faço isso no meu codigo? 

`string GetRandomTetromino(){
  int randomTetromino = Random.Range (1, 5);
  string randomTetrominoName = "Prefabs/C";
  switch (randomTetromino) {
  case 1:
   randomTetrominoName = "Prefabs/H";
   break;
  case 2:
   randomTetrominoName = "Prefabs/C";
   break;
  case 3:
   randomTetrominoName = "Prefabs/H";
   break;
  case 4:
   randomTetrominoName = "Prefabs/C";
   break;
  
  }
  return randomTetrominoName;
 }`

e a variavel `nextTetromino = (GameObject)Instantiate(Resources.Load(GetRandomTetromino()`

Comment: Editei minha resposta pra refletir sua dúvida.

Comment: OK DH eu fiz isso. Ja adicionei as tags aos devidos prefabs, porem da o seguinte erro: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Por que ele nao ta pegando o valor randomico gerado, quando ele da um return randomTetrominoName; Como vou saber qual caso ele pegou e como atribuir a tag? pq a logica da tag peguei, mas como faço para comparar se o valor randomico é da tag H  ou C? seria assim?
`case 1:
   randomTetrominoName = "Prefabs/H";
   randomTetrominoName = GameObject.FindWithTag ("H");`

Comment: @CarlosDiego Na verdade, é só fazer `Grid[x,y].tag == "tag"` como já tinha mencionado no começo da reposta. Talvez o `NullReferenceException` que você está tendo é porque espaços da sua grid vão ter `null`, e por isso você vai ter que verificar primeiro(`xpto != null`)se existe um objeto naquela posição antes de ler a `tag` dele.

Comment: DH. meu codigo esta como antes, `if (Grid [x, y].tag == "C")`

Comment: @CarlosDiego Sim, e aí como disse, antes de entrar nessa linha faça uma verificação de nulo: `if(Grid[x,y] != null)`, e aí sim execute o resto do seu código.

Comment: Mano tu pode me passar teu contato? estou precisando mto de sua ajuda..  e vc ja tem experiencia nessa area. Gostaria de trocar umas ideis ctg e quem sabe tu poder me desempancar nesse projetinho. To tentando aqui com o que vc falou por ultimo. vlw

Comment: DH o que vc falou deu certo em partes.. ele nao da mais erro, porem o contador continua em 0. Mas sinto que to no caminho pra que essa logica funcione

Comment: @CarlosDiego Isso era esperado, tu não pode percorrer uma matriz a cada frame do jogo. Você tem que fazer esse verificação só depois que a "peça" cair, aí você poderia verificar o array todo. Como você ainda não tem reputação pra ir pro chat, recomendo fazer uma nova pergunta caso venha a ter outros problemas :)

Comment: Entendi, estou fazendo novas perguntas afim de adquirir reputaçao o suficiente e conhecimento para aprimorar meu jogo. Ai no caso eu to chamando a funçao `Cecks()` no meu `Update()`, entao eu retiro e coloco dentro da funçao onde o meu objeto cai que da certo? abç e mais uma vez mto obgdo por me ajudar.